# Why forEach won't loop through the entire Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I only use console.log() inside the forEach method it logs all the Array elements,
but when I use the .push(array.pop()) inside it, it stops at some of the elements?

```
const sentence = ['sense.','make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];

function reverseArray(array) {
   debugger;
   let newArray = [];

   array.forEach((arr) => {
     newArray.push(array.pop())
     console.log(arr) 
   })

  return newArray;
}

console.log(reverseArray(sentence))
// RESULT [
//  "This",
//  "will",
//  "all"
// ]
```

But here it works

```
const sentence = ['sense.','make', 'all', 'will', 'This'];

function reverseArray(array) {
   debugger;

   array.forEach((arr) => {
     console.log(arr) 
   })
}

reverseArray(sentence)
// Now it works
// RESULT
// sense.
// VM94:7 make
// VM94:7 all
// VM94:7 will
// VM94:7 This
```

Comment: Do you realize what pop does? You are taking the elements from the end, by the time it gets there, the elements are gone, nothing to loop.

Comment: `arr.pop()` modifies `arr`

Comment: It is a exercise and I am not allowed to use `.reverse()`

Comment: @epascarello, I forgot about that.

Comment: You don't want to modify array while iterating over it. So you could use `newArray.unshift(item)` instead of poping the last element from the input array if you have to use `forEach` in your exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying your array while iterating through it. Instead You should use copy of it like so:

```js
Array.from(array).forEach((elm) => {
  newArray.push(array.pop())
  console.log(elm)
})

// another variant for old browsers

array.slice().forEach((elm) => {
  newArray.push(array.pop())
  console.log(elm)
})
```

Or, as you do not need elements in callback, you should use simple `for` loop

```js
const count = array.length
for (let i=0; i < count i++) {
   newArray.push(array.pop())
   console.log(arr) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!